# Insert more than one bit into uint32_t in one step

Tags: c

I have the following function and want to insert more than one bit in one step.

```
uint32_t InsertBit(uint32_t input, uint8_t idx, uint8_t insbit)
{
    return ((insbit + (input >> idx)) << idx) + input;
}
```

like this prototype:

```
 uint32_t InsertBits(uint32_t input, uint8_t idx, uint8_t bits, uint8_t width);
```

The "width" should be the count of bits to be inserted in the step. Insertion mean "insert" with the bits left from the index shifted left and not only replaced.

I can do this with iterative calls with the InsertBit but the generated assembler code is not good also with optimization "on" with arm gcc 6.5.

Comment: Do you also want to clear the lower bits?

Comment: No, insertion at the beginning of the index like the bitfield instruction command "bfi"

Answer (score 0):

width < 32 . Leave it to the compiler.

```
uint32_t InsertBits(uint32_t input, uint8_t idx, uint8_t bits, uint8_t width)
 {
    uint32_t mask = ((1UL << width) - 1) << idx;

    input &= ~mask;
    input |= bits << idx;
    return input;
 }
```

Comment: Your explanation is not clear to me. Maybe making complete sentences and being specific about what "it" is supposed to mean would help.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: @P___J__: Sorry but your solution forget that each bit insertion should shift the bits before the index in the uint32 left. Therefore in the asm routine is a ROR.

Comment: @makurisan it inserts them where needed https://godbolt.org/z/vhjsoz

Comment: What you do is that you replaced something left from the index. This is not what the routine should do.  If you shift your first byte from 0x123 becomes 0x24... if you insert one bit and so on ... Perhaps I expressed it not clearly enough but look at the InsertBit() function.